# How to get access to the RIL.java?

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, android-ndk, ril

I want to get more information about cellular network, beyond the Google API.I want to get acces to `/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/RIL.java`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the question has Qt tag? It supposed to be done with Qt? You should have told that besides the tag then.

Comment: Qt also supports Android development with NDK. So, this is the way I thought about this tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection to get the internal classes.
However, news around Android developers is that Google will soon block access to those APIs (Access by reflection included).

here's a tutorial on Java Reflection: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html